# How to customize text color in Chromium tabs?

Tags: gnome, themes, chromium, gtk

Does anybody by any chance know how to customize the color of the text in Chromium tabs? I know that Chromium loads these colors from the GTK theme that is used. I'm currently using the Arc theme.

I've spent a good few hours now trying to do that myself, editing the `gtk.css` file in `/usr/share/themes/Arc/gtk-3.0`, I even went into the source code for Chromium trying to get some clues as to what CSS selector I should use. However, I couldn't get it to change.

Any help with this attempt would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this Arc theme a compiled theme? Is there something like `gtk.gresource` and `gtk.gresource.xml` in the `gtk-3.0` folder?

Answer (score 3):

**If** you can edit `gtk.css` in your theme's `gtk-3.0` subfolder, the line to edit is this:

```
@define-color theme_fg_color #aa55ff;
```

where `#aa55ff` is the new color.

Unfortunately, other aspects of the browser user interface will also be affected:

- the text color of your bookmarks bar
- the text color of items in folders of your bookmarks bar
- the color of text in the `Customize and control ...` dropdown
- the color of the back, forward, and home icons, and maybe more

[image: Lilac tab text]

And of course, all other gtk3 applications will be affected as well. If you don't want that to happen, make a copy of the theme with a different name and modify the copy. Then you can use

```
GTK_THEME=modified-theme-name chromium-browser
```

to run **only** chromium-browser with the modified theme.

---

**Edit:**

Even though you didn't ask about Firefox, I just like to point out that the Firefox user interface, even after Quantum, is currently far more customizable.

Here's what it looks like before tweaking the tab text color **and** tab background color:

[image: before]

And this is what it looks like after:

[image: after]

All I did was to create a `userChrome.css` file in the folder `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/chrome`. This folder doesn't exist by default. You need to create it.

The contents of `userChrome.css` to get the tab customization shown are:

```
tab { color: #000010 !important; font-size: 16px !important; font-family: Cousine !important; }
tab [selected] { font-family: Cousine !important; color: #ff00ff !important; font-weight: normal !important; font-size: 16px !important;  background: #444 !important; }
```

The advantage of tweaking the `userChrome.css` file is that no other aspects of the browser or other applications are affected.